# ARC lite enabled app crashes on 2nd gen iPod only in Release configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an ARC lite enabled app (ARC enabled without zeroing weak reference, Apple LLVM 4.0). Deployment target set to iOS 4.0. It's been tested on iOS 4.0 to 5.1.1. It always works fine when I use debug build and install through Xcode, but when I create an adhoc build with release configuration, it always crash during launch on 2nd gen iPod with iOS 4.2.1, but works fine on other devices (even 3rd gen iPod with iOS 4.3).

The crash log says
symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
and it crashes when method main is called (then it's dyld_stub_binder, dyld::fastBindLazySymbol)

I did some search and this crash normally happens when an arc enabled library is included in a project without arc. But in my case arc is enabled for the whole project.

Any clues?

Thanks very much.

[EDIT] Update: I can use NSLog to debug the adhoc build.

The main.m is like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSLog(@"ok before entering autorelease pool");
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"ok after entering autorelease pool");
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([XXX class]));
    }
}
```

NSLog(@"ok after entering autorelease pool") gets called successfully, but application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is never entered.

Comment: You can almost certainly get the crash to happen in the debugger by changing the debug action for your scheme to use a release build. I don't know if that will help.

Comment: Thanks JosephH. I'm trying that, but it fails to install by complaining that "No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates", even if I changed the project setting to let "Release" use developer provisioning profile. Maybe the debug mode just won't work with release build?

Comment: It definitely works. There must still be a problem with your codesign settings for the release build; make them identical to the debug build and it'll work.

Comment: Hmmm I restarted the computer and the error is gone. It tries to install the app on the device, but then failed with error: "Could not launch "XXX"    timed out waiting for app to launch". The app reached loading screen, but quitted there, similar to when I was running an adhoc build.

Comment: Following my last comment.. actually it's just Xcode error. The app can launch and works fine when I installed through Xcode (with release configuration) and launched from the device itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's related to the command line build tool. I used to use xcodebuild command to archive the adhoc build:
xcodebuild -scheme myscheme clean build archive

And got this crash.

Then I tried archiving from Xcode, the adhoc build actually works fine on all devices. So weird (keep in mind that the command line built adhoc worked for devices newer than iPod 2nd gen).

For now I'll just use the Archive button in Xcode. But I posted this question in Apple dev forum:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/711334

Answer (score 0):

My answer: **How i come out from the same problem.**

**Steps:**

1.First make the all the changes in the code sign column and make sure that all the setting are work same as you want in the project tab and target tab as well.

2.Just making all the setting in the first step like selecvting correct provsioning and specify accurate bundle indetifier then now make the xcode quit .

3.After 2 step just restart you computer and then make build for the profile that you selected in first step.

Now its working fine ,hope so this answer may be help you as well.Anyway its my solution of the above problem.....:)